# Socket.io authorization function is not updating session data

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I'm trying to use Socket.IO's authorization function to get session data. The problem is that even if I log out and destroy my session, Socket.IO still has the old session information, which is clearly not ideal. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong in the code below?

```
io.set('authorization', function (data, accept) {
    if(data.headers.cookie) {
        data.cookie = parseCookie(data.headers.cookie);
        data.sessionID = data.cookie['express.sid'];
        app.set('mongo-store').get(data.sessionID, function (err, session) {
            console.log(err, session);
      if (err || !session) {
                // if we cannot grab a session, turn down the connection
                accept('Error', false);
      } else {
        // save the session data and accept the connection
        data.session = session;
        accept(null, true);
      }
        });
    } else {
        return accept('No cookie transmitted.', false);
    }
    accept(null, true);
});
```

And here is the connection code:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {  

  var hs = socket.handshake;
  console.log('A socket with sessionID ' + hs.sessionID 
      + ' connected!');
  // setup an inteval that will keep our session fresh
  var intervalID = setInterval(function () {
      // reload the session (just in case something changed,
      // we don't want to override anything, but the age)
      // reloading will also ensure we keep an up2date copy
      // of the session with our connection.
      hs.session.reload( function () { 
          // "touch" it (resetting maxAge and lastAccess)
          // and save it back again.
          hs.session.touch().save();
      });
  }, 60 * 1000);
  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
      console.log('A socket with sessionID ' + hs.sessionID 
          + ' disconnected!');
      // clear the socket interval to stop refreshing the session
      clearInterval(intervalID);
  });
});
```

Comment: +1 I'm having the same issue. Even if the client's session cookie expires or is deleted, the Socket.IO connection still has access to the old data and believes the session is still active.

Answer (score 4):

From http://www.danielbaulig.de/socket-ioexpress/

```
sio.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    var hs = socket.handshake;
    console.log('A socket with sessionID ' + hs.sessionID 
        + ' connected!');
    // setup an inteval that will keep our session fresh
    var intervalID = setInterval(function () {
        // reload the session (just in case something changed,
        // we don't want to override anything, but the age)
        // reloading will also ensure we keep an up2date copy
        // of the session with our connection.
        hs.session.reload( function () { 
            // "touch" it (resetting maxAge and lastAccess)
            // and save it back again.
            hs.session.touch().save();
        });
    }, 60 * 1000);
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('A socket with sessionID ' + hs.sessionID 
            + ' disconnected!');
        // clear the socket interval to stop refreshing the session
        clearInterval(intervalID);
    });

});
```

Edit: auth code

```
io.set('authorization', function (handshakeData, callback) {
  var cookie;
  // console.log(handshakeData.headers);
  if (handshakeData.headers && handshakeData.headers.cookie) {
    cookie = parseCookie(handshakeData.headers.cookie);
    // where SessionStore is an instance of your mongo store
    SessionStore.load(cookie['sioapp.sid'], function (err, session) {
      if (err) {
        // if we cannot grab a session, turn down the connection
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        // console.log('Successfully decoded the session: ', session);
        handshakeData.session = session;
      }
    });
  }
  callback(null, true); // error first callback style
});
```

Once every 60 seconds, the session is touched (thus refreshed). When the user disconnects, the session is destroyed.

Comment: We're both using code from the same article. I'm using the authorization code found further up the page, but my problem is that my `sessionID` (as used in `hs.sessionID`) is either not correct or the relation between the socket session and Express' session store is simply not working as expected.

Comment: I think what we're both missing is `hs.session.destroy()` in the `disconnect` method. Does that sound right to you?

Comment: Only if you want to completely destroy the session on disconnect. I just wanted to stop "touching" it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the 60 * 1000 means 60 mn. I would say it is 1 mn.

Comment: It's miliseconds. 1000 ms * 60 is 60 seconds.